# IE9 Unable to get value of the property 'documentElement'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have some code that reads data from an .xml file below. In IE Quirks mode all data is retrieved fine, however in IE9 I get the error:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'documentElement': object is null or undefined
```

Here is the code

```
function buildFiledTypeMap() {
        var vXmlDoc = document.getElementById("fieldmeta").XMLDocument;
        var flds=vXmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("field");
```

Snippet from the .jsp displaying this data:

```
<xml id="fieldmeta">
    <c:out value="${myForm.fieldMetaXML}" escapeXml="false"/>
</xml>
```

It is my understanding that documentElement is a valid reference to the root node of the document, so I'm not sure what to update this code to make it IE9-compatible. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you have an element with id fieldmeta ? Paste the html snippet please

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement) documentation shows `.documentElement` being used with the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) rather than an element inside the document. Never used this before myself, but this may be where the problem stems from.

Comment: @Pracede updated to include .jsp snippet. War10ck, I checked the MDN docs but cannot find an explanation of the different browser standards regarding .documentElement

Answer (score 0):

use 
    **${myForm.fieldmetaXML}**
instead of 
    **${myForm.fieldMetaXML}**

IE9 is case sensitive

Comment: then You can change the case for ID and in document.getElementById(here) and make it same as c:out

Comment: Hi @RahulKT, maybe I don't understand fully but, how would that help?

Comment: Hi Clay .... 
Its Just a possible solution... IE9 is fully case sensitive..Its trying to fetch the property of documentElement but its getting null or undefined Object ...